# Chemistry package for typesetting nuclide

Tags: typography, chemistry

Is there a chemistry package with a specific command for typesetting nuclide?

If not, what is the preferred method for typing this?

Here is what I have myself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
$\ce{^{14}_{7}C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ce` doesn't have to be used in math mode, it works in text mode as well. The same is a little bit easier with `chemmacros` as there the subscript shift is not needed: `\ch{^{14}7C}`

Comment: BTW: [I know I lot of chemistry related packages](http://www.mychemistry.eu/known-packages/) but I believe that `mhchem` or `chemmacros` are your best choices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment: I know about a lot of chemistry related packages and [maintain a list](http://www.mychemistry.eu/known-packages/) which I hope is rather complete (if something's missing let me know).

That being said I believe you already made a good choice. The packages [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) and [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) are probably the easiest for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mhchem,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

mhchem: \ce{^{14}_7N}

chemmacros: \ch{^{14}7N}

\end{document}
```

[image]