# Do a chemical notation of an element

Tags: chemistry

So, at school (outside the US) our teacher has given us this type of chemical notation:

[image: notation]

Where Ar is the relative atomic mass, Z atomic number, p protons, n neutrons.
Example:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I want to make a macro out of it, but there's a porblem with \atomicnumber, I think it returns a string instead of an integer or something:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{bohr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{neutron}
\newcommand{\mychemistry}[2]{\setcounter{neutron}{\numexpr#2-\atomicnumber{#1}\relax}\ch{^{#2}\atomicnumber{#1}#1}\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{ \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {+\atomicnumber{#1}};}(\atomicnumber{#1} p,\theneutron n)}
\begin{document}
\mychemistry{O}{18}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only difficulty there is to put a prescript (`\prescript` from `mathtools` package, for instance, would work), and to draw the circle around an element (`tikz` package would do). There are lots of answers here in this site for doing so. However, may be you want an easy way to type that *automatically*… perhaps adding more info to the question would help. What input would you expect? A minimal compilable example would be great to invite us to help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't find any question in your post. This is not a "do it for me" homepage. Where are you having problems, what have you tried. Where is your example code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried looking at http://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry ?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I haven't used LaTex that much, so this is why I didn't include code in my question. If you could at least show me an example I would appreciate it very much. I don't know if there are functions in LaTex, like to do it automatically, but I guess if you could also show me that it would be great. I will look into the site, thank you.

Comment: @user2563892 Anyways, an example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` of *something*, just so we can copy that code and start working from there rather than typing it ourselves, is always welcome.

Comment: Well, I think there's no need for that, the only problem is putting a letter in a circle and making it text. And I have no experience what so ever. There's no need for a full document, just an example that I could use.

Comment: @user2563892 : if three comments ask you to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (an example code), I think you should interpret it as *there is a need for that*, at least to show us your good will to solve your problem. We won't solve it for you, you know, just provide some hints and directions for further studies.

Comment: Thank you for your "help". \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\ce{^{Ar}_{Z}El}\circled{+Z}(Z p, Ar-Z n)
\end{document}

Comment: Too bad I can't yet answer my own question

Comment: For the nuclides see [Chemistry package for typesetting nuclide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115793/chemistry-package-for-typesetting-nuclide). Also maybe interesting: the [`bohr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bohr) provides `\atomicnumber{<element>}` (e.g. `\atomicnumber{F}` gives `9`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit 2015-12-14 – adapt to use `elements` package**

The idea is the same as in the original answer, see below. The `bohr` package doesn't provide `\atomicnumber` any more. It is now provided by the `elements` package. The latter also provides `\saveatomicnumber<cs>{<element>}` which makes the macro a little bit easier:

```
\saveatomicnumber\@tmp{#1}
```

and then

```
\the\numexpr#2-\@tmp\relax
```

for the number of neutrons.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{elements}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mychemistry[2]{%
  \saveatomicnumber\@tmp{#1}%
  \ch{^{#2}_{\atomicnumber{#1}}#1}
  \tikz[baseline]{
    \node[anchor=base,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt]
    {+\atomicnumber{#1}};
  }
  (%
    \atomicnumber{#1} p,
    \the\numexpr#2-\@tmp\relax
    n%
  )%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mychemistry{O}{18}
\end{document}
```

---

**Earlier answer using the `bohr` package**

An answer to the edited question: `\atomicnumber` is not expandable and as a consequence not usable in `\numexpr ... \relax`. However, if you're certain that you only input the element *symbol* and never the element *name* you can use the internal command. For the element `F` this is `\@bohr@atom@number@f`, for `Ne` it's `\@bohr@atom@number@ne` and so on.

In order to use it with uppercase atomic symbols as input you need to `\lowercase{...}` the input. `\lowercase` again is not expandable but you can simply surround the `\setcounter` part with it. Actually, the counter isn't even needed since it is only used to determine the number of neutrons. It is possible to use `\numexpr` directly by preceding it with `\the`.  In order to build the needed macro name we can use the primitives `\csname...\endcsname` or LaTeX's wrapper `\@nameuse{...}`, both of which are expandable. In the command this would then be something like `\csname @bohr@atom@number@#1\endcsname` or `\@nameuse{@bohr@atom@number@#1}`.

Putting this together you can get the number of neutrons with

```
\lowercase{\the\numexpr#2-\csname @bohr@atom@number@#1\endcsname\relax}
```

or

```
\lowercase{\the\numexpr#2-\@nameuse{@bohr@atom@number@#1}\relax}
```

Adapting you example, I added indentation and [comment chars where needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) but I also left a space between the different parts since it looked more readable to me this way. I also omitted to name the `\node` since alignment with the baseline can also be achieved with `anchor=base` as option to the node.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}% the package that provides `\ch` and which is loaded by `chemmacros'
\usepackage{bohr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mychemistry[2]{%
  \ch{^{#2}_{\atomicnumber{#1}}#1}
  \tikz[baseline]{
    \node[anchor=base,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt]
    {+\atomicnumber{#1}};
  }
  (%
    \atomicnumber{#1} p,
    \lowercase{\the\numexpr#2-\csname @bohr@atom@number@#1\endcsname\relax}
      n%
  )%
}
\begin{document}
\mychemistry{O}{18}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: if you use `chemmacros` already you can also easily output protons as p<sup>+</sup> and neutrons as n<sup>0</sup>:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{bohr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mychemistry[2]{%
  \ch{^{#2}_{\atomicnumber{#1}}#1}
  \tikz[baseline]{
    \node[anchor=base,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt]
    {+\atomicnumber{#1}};
  }
  (%
    \atomicnumber{#1} \prt, % <<<<<<<<<
    \lowercase{\the\numexpr#2-\csname @bohr@atom@number@#1\endcsname\relax}
      \ntr % <<<<<<<<<
  )%
}
\begin{document}
\mychemistry{O}{18}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\prt` actually just is the equivalent of `\chcpd{p+}` and `\ntr` is `\chcpd{n^0}` so `chemmacros` isn't really needed and `chemformula` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was a little angry yesterday, but learning is always help.

Comment: Also, why do you put percent signs, aren't they comments?

Comment: Ends of lines are treated like spaces. If I don't want them to cause spurious spaces in the result I need to hide them by commenting them out. There's a question about this somewhere on this site...

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Comment: @user2563892 I added some explanations to my answer

Answer (score 8):

Is that what you want? I define a `\chemelt` command, with a very simple syntax: enter the comma-separated list of the element symbol, the atomic number and the atomic mass (in that order). It requires loading `pstricks` (for the circle box), with `pdf`option to compile with pdfLaTeX, `xparse` (for the simple syntax) and `mathtools` (for the  `prescript` command).

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, pdf]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
    \usepackage{lmodern} 

    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \newcounter{neutron}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{xparse}

    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\chemelt}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}
    {\chemeltaux#1}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\chemeltaux}{mmm}{\setcounter{neutron}{\numexpr#3-#2\relax}\def\C{\pscirclebox{+8}} \ensuremath{\mathrm{\prescript{#3}{#2}#1}}\raisebox{-0.25\height}{\scriptsize\pscirclebox[framesep = 1pt, linewidth = 0.6pt]{+#2} (#2p,\theneutron n)}}

    \begin{document}

    \chemelt{O, 8,16}\\

    \chemelt{F, 9,19}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, op told in a (moderately polite) comment that he already found a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and work, but as Clement already mentioned, I've found a solution. Again, thanks, at least someone decided to help an absolute noob. :)

Comment: What is the `\def\C{\pscirclebox{+8}}` there for?

Comment: @cgnieder: For nothing. It's a remnant of a first attempt. Thanks for pointing it. I cleaned the code.